# TextBox Example Into Datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I have simple textbox example as below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Apple";
    }
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1) 
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "B" || textBox1.Text == "b") 
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Ball";
            }
        }
    }
```

By default textbox1 should return "Apple" on Form load but when I press "b" or "B" then it should return "Ball" on textbox1. I have a confusion on utilize it into datagridview. how can i do it in datagridview?.

Suppose I have One column on datagridview like below:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn Particulars = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, Particulars );
    }
```

If I have above column In datagridview1 than How to do I with datagridview1 which I have did with textbox?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You might find it more straightforward to use the auto-complete functionality built-in to the textbox control, rather than trying to code for all possible scenarios yourself.**

There are two important properties of the `TextBox` control that you must configure to enable its auto-completion functionality: **`AutoCompleteMode`** and **`AutoCompleteSource`**.

The **[`AutoCompleteMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode.aspx)** property allows you to choose *how* the textbox autocomplete function will look in action. You can choose between any of the [`AutoCompleteMode` values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx)

```
None            Disables the automatic completion feature for the ComboBox and TextBox controls.
Suggest         Displays the auxiliary drop-down list associated with the edit control. This drop-down is populated with one or more suggested completion strings.
Append          Appends the remainder of the most likely candidate string to the existing characters, highlighting the appended characters.
SuggestAppend   Applies both Suggest and Append options.
```

The **[`AutoCompleteSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource.aspx)** property allows you to specify the strings that you want the textbox to propose auto-completion with. In your case, you will probably want to specify a `CustomSource`, which requires you to set the **[`AutoCompleteCustomSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx)** property to a user-defined collection of strings—something like "Apple, Ball, ..." etc.

The `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` simply hosts a standard `TextBox` control, so all of the auto-complete functionality it provides is already available to you for free. You can set the appropriate properties of this textbox by handling the `EditingControlShowing` event of your `DataGridView`, like so:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    //Create and fill a list to use as the custom data source
    var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    source.AddRange(new string[] {"Apple", "Ball"});

    //Set the appropriate properties on the textbox control
    TextBox dgvEditBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (dgvEditBox != null)
    {
        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** If you'd prefer to keep the same behavior as you have in the original textbox example, you can just **handle the `TextChanged` event for the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`**. As I already explained above, the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` simply hosts a standard `TextBox` control, so it's fairly straightforward to add a handler for its `TextChanged` event and use the same code you had before:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox dgvEditBox = e.Control as TextBox;
    if (dgvEditBox != null)
    {
        //Add a handler for the TextChanged event of the underlying TextBox control
        dgvEditBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dgvEditBox_TextChanged);
    }
}

private void dgvEditBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Extract the textbox control
    TextBox dgvEditBox = (TextBox)sender;

    //Insert the appropriate string
    if (dgvEditBox.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        if (dgvEditBox.Text == "B" || dgvEditBox.Text == "b")
        {
            dgvEditBox.Text = "Ball";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cody, Your code is works and i am appreciated the way you explain it. just edit your code. You forget to add ";" to "dgvEditBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source"

Comment: ...One more thing I like to tell you that In my case there is straight collection works not like collection of string you suggested.

Comment: ... Your way is too good. but certain case it's possible like my code with textbox as above.

Comment: neccessary. if you have other way than please suggest.

Comment: @mahesh: I'm sorry, I really didn't understand what you were trying to say. You're saying that you can't just place your strings into a collection? Why not?

Comment: @Cody I want to say that your idea is fulfill my requirement but I didn't want this way. I don't want to show collection of string to user.

Comment: ... if there is only two items like above than is it possible with dgv to what i did above with textbox?.

Comment: .. i mean any different way with dgv.

Comment: @mahesh: I understand now. I updated my answer with another solution; see if this is more in line with what you want.

Comment: @Cody, Yes you did it but there is little problem. the way you utilize  it on dgv. it's affect all columns of the dgv. suppose this above example is for one columns.

Comment: @mahesh: Yes. If you want to limit it to certain columns, you'll need to check which column you're in and only add the event handler when you're in an appropriate column number.

Comment: ... now if i add one more columns on it. than if i press b on other columns it would definitely  show "Ball" on other columns. i just wants to restrict it up to one columns.it should not affect other columns.

Comment: @Cody, You are right now. I would definitely going to accept your answer but it's request to complete your code as suggested by me. It would lots help to others. Or final decision I leave upto you.